# How to make edittext scrollable in android kotlin?

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollbar

here is XML code:-

```
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/Description"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingVertical="8dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/Description_et"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/description"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:isScrollContainer="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Here is my activity code:-

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details)

        Description_et.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
    }
```

I tried using this method but it is not working for me. It is scrollabel using pointer and by selecting text. But I want to scroll it without using pointer.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to scroll it without using pointer` ?

Comment: I want to scroll by touching the screen.

Comment: Like how it is done in WhatsApp. For scrolling we have move the pointer but I want to scroll without moving the pointer